# Need Help for creating a Component with listener in Adobe CQ 5.4

Tags: java, aem

I am new to Adobe CQ 5.4 please suggest a good tutorial where I can learn and implement , to create a component with a listener attached , perform some basic operation on trigger of the event,I am using Java for the developing components.

Regards,
Yash

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest first checking out Adobe's documentation... 
http://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/current/howto/components_develop.html

CQ ships with a reference site implementation called Geometrixx.  It comes with a full suite of working components that you can use to learn.  You can examine the sample code either through CRXDE (Lite) by visiting  the example component's render scripts under /libs/geometrixx.

- On how Sling script resolution works (will tell you how to determine what code is responsible for rendering a specific component and where it would live in the repository):
  http://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/current/developing/the_basics.html
- On creating a component with a specific event listener, you can easily do this by using plain old JavaScript in your component code.